# Launcher icon duplicated when I launch Android Studio, why?

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, android-studio

I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS with the default Unity desktop. Down the left hand side is the launcher bar/taskbar, with icons for all the apps I use. Above the ordinary housekeeping apps I have Eclipse and Android Studio installed and associated launcher bar icons.

Alone amongst all the apps, when I start A.Sudio via the taskbar, the icon is duplicated and appears again at the bottom above the wastepaper basket. When that app is in the background clicking on the original launcher icon does nothing, only the newly created bottom icon is active. For all other apps (Eclipse, Thunderbird, Firefox etc) clicking on the sole original icon switches focus to that task when it's in the background.

Can anyone please explain this behaviour of Android Studio and its icon?

Comment: Could be several issues, of which the most likely is a local .destop file in `~/.local/share/applications` how did you install?

Comment: @JacobVlijm. I can't remember how I installed it, as it was a brand new laptop which I changed from Windows. It's the first time I've used Android Studio. However I have got a .desktop file for A. Studio in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: If you also have one in `/usr/share/applications` please remove the local one, log out and back in. Please let me know!

Comment: I don't have an android-studio.desktop in /usr/share/applications. There is however a jetbrains-studio.desktop in usr/share/applications. I don't know exactly what jet-brains is but it has some connection to a. studio

Comment: @JacobVlijm I seem to have fixed it somehow. I renamed the local .desktop to .WASdesktop. The icon disappeared. I restored the file name to .desktop. The icon didn't reappear!?. So, I launched a.s from the command line and locked it to launcher. Now it behaves itself. I don't understand what I've done but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying the desktop file (jetbrains-studio.desktop for me)
This file if created by android studio contains the line:

> StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio

while the one created by umake contains:

> StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio

change it to

> StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio

and save it, You might need super user permissions (sudo) for the same.

Reference: https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/270#issue-142174619

Answer (score 1):

[Himanshu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/829718/1157209) is correct, but slightly outdated.

I had to add the line:

```
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

to the file `/usr/share/applications/studio.desktop`. Before I used the command:

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

to verify the correct value. Note that the `xprop` command may not work with Wayland.